# Excute commands in putty from batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, putty

I have AT command:

```
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGS="+995557525253"
> This is the text message.→
+CMGS: 198
OK
```

This command works fine via putty serial.
I want to send this code from Batch file to Putty.
or other file which automatically make this commands.

COM port is: COM14

I am using SAMSUNG as GMS modem.
This is connected my PC VIA USB cable.

how to do this, is this possible? :)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
echo AT+CMGF=1 > COM14
.
.
.
echo AT > COM14
```

COM14 suggests that you're using a USB to Serial converter though, so that port number may change if you unplug it, or restart, or change settings related to it.

I found this link as well, which may have some useful further info:
http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-trick-for-sending-characters-to-a-serial-port-in-windows/

Comment: What do you mean by CMD returns nothing?  Does the SMS not get sent at all?  Can you communicate with the modem by reading characters back at all using redirection operators?

Comment: I am trying to use Plink. plink work fine but wen I send AT+CMGS="+31628870634 open new line with this prefix ">" and I can not send Ctrl+Z click action.